# How to do Nested Queries in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, dataset, querying

I'm trying to learn SQL, and while I'm slowly learning how to query data, I'm stuck on querying the results of a query. Take this example

I want an SQL statement to do 2 things. Suppose I have 2 tables like the one below (table 1 borrowed from another example on stack overflow)

Table 1:

```
ID  game   point  time
1    x      5     7:00
1    z      4     11:00
2    y      6     9:00
3    x      2     2:00
3    y      5     4:00
3    z      8     6:00
4    k      0     8:00
```

Table 2:

```
id  tv chan
1    cab  
2    trop  
3    start   
4    cab
```

The first thing I want to do is combine certain columns from these tables. I know I can select these columns and do an inner join on ID

However the second thing I want to do is drop all the rows with point value 0, and then have only rows with distinct game name with the lowest point value. So I want the final table to look like this

```
id  game   point   tv chan    
1    z      4       cab
2    y      5       trop
3    x      2       start
```

Thanks

Comment: Minimum point for game y is 5 (not 6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT t1.ID, 
       t1.game, 
       t1.point, 
       t2.tv_chan 
FROM Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT t11.game, MIN(t11.point) AS min_point  
            FROM Table1 AS t11 
            WHERE t11.point != 0 
            GROUP BY t11.game
           ) AS t3 ON t3.game = t1.game
                      AND t3.min_point = t1.point 
WHERE t1.point != 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use  a join with a subquery that group by id and game for obtain the min point

```
    select t1.id, t1.game. t1.point, t2 `tv chan`
    from (
        select id, game,  min(point) point
        from table1
        where point > 0
        group by id, game
    ) t1 
    inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```